# Ipython qtconsole cannot find installed PyQt (Homebrew)

Tags: python, pyqt, homebrew, python-3.3, qtconsole

I have been trying to install Python 3.3.2 + ipython 1.0 with qtconsole, all via Homebrew. This requires me to download and install PyQt, which I have done successfully. However, when I try to run $ipython3 qtconsole, it cannot load PyQt4 - it says it isn't installed. I think the problem might have something to do with adding the correct PYTHONPATH - after installing PyQt I got some warnings:

```
Your PYTHONPATH points to a site-packages dir for Python 2.x but you are running Python 3.x!
 PYTHONPATH is currently: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
 You should `unset PYTHONPATH` to fix this.

For non-homebrew python (2.x), you need to amend your PYTHONPATH like so:
 export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

Also, I cannot see the PATH that it emphasizes in my .profile.

I followed this guide:
http://www.lowindata.com/2013/installing-scientific-python-on-mac-os-x/

I tried adding several different PYTHONPATH to .profile, but none seems to work.

Any suggestions or workarounds?

**UPDATE:** 
I located the PyQt in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages, but I need to install it in /python3.3/site-packages .. My PATH is /usr/local/bin, and Homebrew installed everything else into the python3.3, except PyQt. How do I get it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build PyQt with python3 support. So:

```
brew install pyqt --with-python3
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I get the following error though:

Error: pyqt dependency sip not installed with:
  --with-python3

Comment: `brew reinstall sip --with-python3` :)

Comment: Thank you, guess I asked too quickly - figured it ;). Hope it works now.

Comment: Thanks! Just a quick heads up: if you get an error with `import sipconfig`, just launch python3 and do `>>> import sipconfig` and then `brew install pyqt --with-python3` again.

Comment: This command to install with python3 support seems to no longer work with Homebrew. Others might find this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34583811/how-can-i-install-pyqt5-on-mac) helpful.