# How can I install PyQt5 on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pyqt, installation

I am trying to install PyQt5 on my Mac but I do not know how to use it well. I have tried to install sip doing

```
cd ~/Downloads/sip-4.17
python configure.py
```

which worked, and then I tried

```
cd ~/Downloads/PyQt-gpl-5.5.1
python configure.py --qmake /Users/name/Qt/5.5/clang_64/bin/qmake
```

which returns an error that says

Make sure you have a working sip on your PATH or use the --sip argument to explicitly specify a working sip.

How do I fix this error? Did I not install sip?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm kind of dodging the question, but the simplest way is to install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), and just run `brew install pyqt` or `brew install pyqt5`.

Comment: Disclaimer: This will install python 3.x on your system, as it seems to be listed as a dependency. I myself was quite surprised, as i thought PyQT5 supported python>2.6. Not sure if noob or just stupid.

Comment: How do I import this in my python script? My code cannot find the module.

Comment: @TinoCaer probably you are running the wrong python; try `python --version` and see if it match the python required by your QT version

Comment: Sorry, I really think Christian's answer is better. pip3 is much cleaner, faster and simpler.

Comment: Thanks, Tim! And it is worth mentioning that it is really against Python's way to install it. Meanwhile people are trying to build a PySide2 install with homebrew, too. What a bad idea since we are building wheels for Python. There should be _one_ standard way for all platforms...

Answer (score 42):

Meanwhile I have the ultimate way to install PyQt5 on macOS.
Don't use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). It is great for installing Qt5, but for PyQt5 the best way to install it is using

```
python3 -m pip install PyQt5
```

This works very quickly and uses universal Python Wheels:

```
Collecting PyQt5
  Downloading PyQt5-5.9-5.9.1-cp35.cp36.cp37-abi3-macosx_10_6_intel.whl 
(82.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 82.2MB 17kB/s 
Collecting sip<4.20,>=4.19.3 (from PyQt5)
  Downloading sip-4.19.3-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (49kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 1.2MB/s 
Installing collected packages: sip, PyQt5
Successfully installed PyQt5-5.9 sip-4.19.3
```

You see: Such a wheel is re-used for CPython 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7.

Old remark, but see below: PySide2 is not as far, but we will build similar wheels when we have the first version ready.

*Added on 2017/09/25: You can of course also use*

```
pip3 install PyQt5
```

*But at that time my pip/pip2/pip3 was a bit messy linked, so the first solution is rock solid and avoids confusion.*

Also right is that you don't always get the lastest version of PyQt5 this way. But for getting started, the priority is to get results quickly and not the bleeding edge.

Update: PySide2 now officially has wheels, to:

```
$ python3 -m pip install PySide2
Collecting pyside2
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2a/e2/2dc134a5c475f661d5ff2ab587fbd2c285db3d064e03ac9b4a2ee0958400/PySide2-5.12.2-5.12.2-cp35.cp36.cp37-abi3-macosx_10_12_intel.whl (109.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 109.8MB 238kB/s 
Collecting shiboken2==5.12.2 (from pyside2)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/8b/a2ad76c3a935fae51f0ed9b150a9df08167c4550fcd07637f0db19c31849/shiboken2-5.12.2-5.12.2-cp35.cp36.cp37-abi3-macosx_10_12_intel.whl (691kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 696kB 1.6MB/s 
Installing collected packages: shiboken2, pyside2
Successfully installed pyside2-5.12.2 shiboken2-5.12.2
```

If you see bugs or differences between the two, please feel free to open a bug report. Follow the instructions on https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python/Reporting_Bugs

Comment: No, in my case. SIP doesn't follow. I have to home-brew later.

Comment: This is not true. I just tried it again. Works like a charm with pip. There is only one drawback: You get the .pyi stub files only with the brew version.

Comment: » pip install PyQt5                                                                                                                               
Collecting PyQt5
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt5 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PyQt5

Comment: Please bear with me for a very uninformed question. Would that install all that is needed to get started with Python 3 and Qt, or is it just about Python bindings for a separately installed and supposed pre existent Qt5 installation?

Comment: @mico I think it will install PyQt5 and Qt5 also on Windows, at least PySide2 does that. You need to install Python 3.X yourself.

Comment: I'm on macOS Big Sur … I did this (and tried homebrew as well which seemed install but "import PyQt5" fails in ) and it is giving me errors:
Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [29 lines of output]

Comment: My answer is now 6 years old, and Big Sur is its own beast. Better open a new question and don't expect that answers are eternal :)

Comment: This post is still accurate, but I should add that updating to the newest version of python can be necessary for the pip command to work properly. So, if it's still giving you errors, check for updates before giving up

Comment: On Monterey `python3 -m pip install PyQt5` fails for me, with the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sipbuild'`.   However, `brew install pyqt5` as described below works for me.

Comment: I did `pip3 install sip` which worked fine. Then I did `pip3 install PyQt5` but that failed as others above have posted. `Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error`. I have a Mac with an M1 chip in case that is relevant, running MacOS Ventura 13.5.1

Answer (score 4):

You need to install [SIP](https://pypi.org/project/sip/) first, which is not just running `configure.py`:

```
>>> cd ~/Downloads/sip-4.17
>>> python configure.py
>>> make
>>> make install
```

Then you can install PyQt5:

```
>>> cd ~/Downloads/PyQt-gpl-5.5.1
>>> python configure.py --qmake /Users/name/Qt/5.5/clang_64/bin/qmake
>>> make
>>> make install
```

Comment: Yes this should be the accepted answer. Installing PyQt using brew will be a bit of a mess I think (using brew for python lib is a bad idea IMO). Installing Qt using brew can be done but the formula is not up to date with the pyqt sources (5.8.0 vs 5.8.2)

Comment: So I just tried this and I couldn't really manage to install it this way.
In the end I just had to enter `sudo python3 pip3 install PyQt5`

Comment: @Rich_Rich You should avoid sudo. With Python, you can install a virtualenv once and then use that all the time. But if your _brew_ command is correctly installed (check this with _brew doctor_ !), then the brewed Python should work fine, even without virtualenv and without sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Qt is set of cross-platform C++ libraries that implement high-level APIs for accessing many aspects of modern desktop and mobile systems. These include location and positioning services, multimedia, NFC and Bluetooth connectivity, a Chromium based web browser, as well as traditional UI development.

PyQt5 is a comprehensive set of Python bindings for Qt v5. It is implemented as more than 35 extension modules and enables Python to be used as an alternative application development language to C++ on all supported platforms including iOS and Android.

PyQt5 may also be embedded in C++ based applications to allow users of those applications to configure or enhance the functionality of those applications.

```
     brew install PyQt5 (or) pip3 install PyQt5
```

Answer (score 0):

In `~/.pip/pip.log` I discovered:

```
Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/... (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyqt5/) because it is not compatible with this Python
```

Simply installed newwer version of Python 3 from official website and `pip3 install PyQt5` finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

Qt has a Mac .dmg installer with all the components.  I uninstalled my pip version first, and installed my Qt into the standard location - I tried putting into /opt/Qt as suggested by another post, but it failed due to changes to MacOS rights in Mojave. There is an expansion triangle next to the Qt item which allows for installing Designer separately from the Qt engine and the 2D/3D development and platform-specific tools.

Qt Installer:

https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer