# Getting SDK Path error during PyQt5 install

Tags: xcode, macos, pyqt, pyqt5, osx-elcapitan

I'm trying to install PyQt5 (PyQt-gpl-5.5.1) following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34612402/4549865) guide. However, during qmake I'm getting SDK Path error.

```
python configure.py --qmake /path/to/qmake --verbose
Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
Determining the details of your Qt installation...
/opt/local/libexec/qt5/bin/qmake -o qtdetail.mk qtdetail.pro
Project ERROR: Could not resolve SDK Path for 'macosx10.11'
Error: Failed to determine the detail of your Qt installation. Try again using
the --verbose flag to see more detail about the problem.
```

`xcrun --show-sdk-path` and `xcodebuild -sdk -version` shows that the current sdk version is macosx10.12, while PyQt expects macosx10.11 (based on the system version) and forms .pro file accordingly.

As I get it, somewhere in `configure.py` SDK version is defined as system version. Can you please help me to find out where?

Comment: Why not install PyQt using one of the other answers to the question you linked? Do you *need* to build from source?

Comment: @user3419537 Brew packages require brew python (python 3 in my case). However, I need PyQt for python 2.7 (anaconda).

Comment: @user3419537 As for the other answer, `pip install python-qt5` results in [another](https://github.com/hugsy/cemu/issues/13) error, that leads to pretty much the [same](https://gist.github.com/vityafx/e01ab56d28a2c9467cc6) solution: to build from source. I'd like to find a simplier way, but don't know how.

Comment: @user3419537 You were right. `brew install pyqt5` is an easier way to install PyQt. There was no problem with different pythons.